# How to add the AutoMapperConfiguration in Program.cs in asp.net core 6.0

Tags: asp.net-core, automapper, asp.net-core-6.0

How to add the AutoMapperConfiguration in Program.cs in asp.net core 6.0?

I have tried with

Program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);


// Auto Mapper Configurations
   builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Automapper));  // Automapper is my Automapper class name
```

But I got this error when debugging

```
Exception has occurred: CLR/System.InvalidOperationException
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.AspNetCore.dll: 'Cannot modify ServiceCollection after application is built.'
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebApplicationServiceCollection.CheckServicesAccess()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebApplicationServiceCollection.Add(ServiceDescriptor item)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionServiceExtensions.AddSingleton(IServiceCollection services, Type serviceType, Object implementationInstance)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionServiceExtensions.AddSingleton[TService](IServiceCollection services, TService implementationInstance)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.OptionsServiceCollectionExtensions.Configure[TOptions](IServiceCollection services, String name, Action`1 configureOptions)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionExtensions.AddAutoMapperClasses(IServiceCollection services, Action`2 configAction, IEnumerable`1 assembliesToScan, ServiceLifetime serviceLifetime)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionExtensions.AddAutoMapper(IServiceCollection services, Type[] profileAssemblyMarkerTypes)
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in in PaymentApi/Program.cs:line 42
```

Automapper.cs

```
using AutoMapper;
using TechnePaymentApi.Models;

namespace TechnePaymentApi.Utilities;

    public class Automapper : Profile
    {
        public Automapper() {
        
         CreateMap<PaymentRequest, PaymentRequestViewModel>();
         CreateMap<Payment, PaymentViewModel>();
     }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please show the full code?

Comment: I edited my question with Autonmaper.cs. please check

Comment: Your error message suggests you're tying to add services *after* you've called `builder.Build()`: Don't do that.

Comment: @KirkLarkin Thank you. I mistakenly add after this line `var app = builder.Build();`